# If statement running but not processing

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been scratching my head all morning trying to understand why the following doesn't seem to work. The idea here is that if there is no column provided, run 1 set of code and if there is, then run another.

Let's say the value of df just holds 1 value = 'A'

```
def function_name(df, col):
    if col == None:
        df = df.str.lower()

    else:
        df[col] = df[col].str.lower()

function_name(df, None)
```

Expected Results: `'a'`
Current Results: `'A'`

If I was to run `function_name(df, 'A')`:

Expected Results: `'a'`
Current Results: `'a'`

Ideally when running the function, since None was passed in it should return whatever commands I passed through but currently, it's acting as if nothing is happening. When I debug by printing it, I can see that the code is doing the 'stuff' but the function itself isn't resulting in whatever commands was run. Any thoughts?

Comment: "but the function itself isn't resulting in whatever commands was run." I don't understand. What specifically do you think you should see happening, that you don't see happening? What exactly do you see happening instead? Give an *actual*, *complete* example (even if it doesn't reflect your actual code, it should reflect the *problem you are observing*).

Comment: Presumably you know that reassigning the `df` variable inside your function is not going to affect anything outside the function.

Comment: That said, if I am correctly *guessing* your problem, you should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html and make sure you understand the language fundamentals.

Comment: if `df` was  `'A'` then strings dont have a `str` property

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear just updated the post and let me know if that changes your feedback.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect ``df = df.str.lower()`` to do? Do you expect it to modify the ``df`` passed in? Right now it just overwrites the *local name* ``df`` which is discarded it when the function ends.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes. Exactly. 'A' can be a string of anything. The idea is that the first if chunk should be updating the df (which it does) and when I run the function, it should return all the changes made during the function.

Comment: Well, if you want to update the df you must actually update it. Reassigning its name doesn't affect the df at all.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, then why does it update it for the else chunk?

Comment: ``df = ...`` assigns to the name ``df``. ``df[col] = ...`` assigns to the *element ``col`` of* ``df``.

Comment: Thank you master @MisterMiyagi, I overlooked that element!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since i can't comment, i'll post it as an answer.

***df is acting as two data types***, in the if block it is not an array, whereas in else block it is acting as an array so please check it out. You can do **df[0]** in the first block.

Moreover you mentioned that the function isn't returning anything, this is due to the missing return statement, So if you intend to return the new df add **return df** at the end of the function.

Comment: Just updated post, I don't want to return anything. I'm just using the function to do a bunch of dataframe updates to the same dataframe.

Comment: I think this is actually not bad as an answer – it certainly does not look like a comment. Note however that "df is acting as two data types" is not how Python works – the object initially assigned to ``df`` is whatever it is (most likely a pandas dataframe) no matter how it is used. However, in the first branch the *local name* ``df`` just is replaced.

Comment: thanks @GNour, your post was the right idea. I was trying make column level changes to a series assuming that since it was a 1d series, the variable would hold any changes made to it. Changing df[0]=pd.Series(df[0]).str.lower() fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say, You're passing df which just holds 1 value = 'A'. So, the code

```
def function_name(df, col):
    if col == None:
        df = str(df).lower()

    else:
        df[col] = str(df).lower()
    print(df)

function_name('A', None)
```

you're expecting an output `a` when you're passing `'A'`, and the function does not return any value. So, I tried printing the value of df and its matching the expected output. The .(dot) operator is used to access class, structure, union members, and str is a datatype, so using df.str.lower() leads to `AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'df'`.  I hope this answer helps.